# How to ignore implicit zeros with scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.min?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, nearest-neighbor

### Goal

I have a list of about 500K points in 3D space. I want to find the two coordinates with the maximum first nearest neighbor distance.

### Approach

I am using scipy to calculate a sparse distance matrix:

```py
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree

tree = cKDTree(points, 40)
spd = tree.sparse_distance_matrix(tree, 0.01)
spo = spd.tocsr()
spo.eliminate_zeros()
```

I eliminate explicit zeros to account for the diagonal elements where the distance between each point and itself is calculated.

I wanted to now find the coordinates of the minimum distance in each row/column, which should correspond to the first nearest neighbor of each point, with something like:

```py
spo.argmin(axis=0)
```

By finding the maximum distance for the elements in this array I should be able to find the two elements with the maximum first nearest neighbor distance.

### The problem

The issue is that the `min` and `argmin` functions of `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix` also take the implicit zeros into account, which for this application I do not want. How do I solve this issue? With this huge matrix, performance and memory are both issues. Or is there an entirely different approach to what I want to do?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a solution with the distance matrix but it appears I overlooked the most obvious solution using the `query` method of the tree.

So to find the maximum distance between first nearest neighbors I did (with vectors a numpy array of shape (N, 3)):

```py
tree = cKDTree(vectors, leaf_size)
# get the indexes of the first nearest neighbor of each vertex
# we use k=2 because k=1 are the points themselves with distance 0
nn1 = tree.query(vectors, k=2)[1][:,1]
# get the vectors corresponding to those indexes. Basically this is "vectors" sorted by
# first nearest neighbor of each point in "vectors".
nn1_vec = vectors[nn1]
# the distance between each point and its first nearest neighbor
nn_dist = np.sqrt(np.sum((vectors - nn1_vec)**2, axis=1))
# maximum distance
return np.max(nn_dist)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case any one finds this later (like me).  Here's a slightly simpler version.  Thanks DIN14970 for doing all the research on this.

Turns out `.query` returns the distances (may not have been the case when originally asked).  No need to compute them.

```py
tree = cKDTree(vectors, leaf_size)
# get the indexes of the first nearest neighbor of each vertex
# we use k=2 because k=1 are the points themselves with distance 0
nn1_distance = tree.query(vectors, k=2)[1][0][:,1]
# maximum distance
return np.max(nn1_distance)
```