# How to ignore implicit zeros using scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.minimum?

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have two matrices `mat1` and `mat2` that are sparse (most entries are zero) and I'm not interested in the zero-valued entries: I look at the matrices from a graph-theoretical perspective where a zero means that there is no edge between the nodes.

How can I *efficiently* get the minimum values **between non-zero entries only** using `scipy.sparse` matrices?
I.e. an equivalent of `mat1.minimum(mat2)` that would ignore implicit zeros.

Using dense matrices, it is fairly easy to do:

```py
import numpy as np
nnz = np.where(np.multiply(mat1, mat2))
m = mat1 + mat2
m[nnz] = np.minimum(mat1[nnz], mat2[nnz])
```

But this would be very inefficient with sparse matrices.

**NB:** a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64198981/how-to-ignore-implicit-zeros-with-scipy-sparse-csr-matrix-min) has been asked before but did not get any relevant answer and there is a related [PR](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/pull/11899) on the scipy repo that proposes an implementation of this for (arg)min/max but not for `minimum`.

EDIT: to specify a bit more the desired behavior would be commutative, i.e. this `nonzero-minimum` would take all values present in only one of the two matrices and the min of the entries that are present in both matrices

Comment: I can imagine doing this with the `csr` attributes, iterating "row-by-row", (or possibly the `lil` format).  But it would require some work, and I can't predict the performance.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone also looks for this, my current implementation is below.
However, I'd appreciate any proposal that would either speed this up or reduce the memory footprint.

```py
s = mat1.multiply(mat2)
s.data[:] = 1.

a1 = mat1.copy()
a1.data[:] = 1.
a1 = (a1 - s).maximum(0)

a2 = mat2.copy()
a2.data[:] = 1.
a2 = (a2 - s).maximum(0)

res = mat1.multiply(a1) + mat2.multiply(a2) + \
      mat1.multiply(s).minimum(mat2.multiply(s))
```

Answer (score 0):

**If the sparse nonzeros are positive**, an alternate way to use the correct *UNION* behavior of `maximum` might
be to *negate and make positive*.

Following your lead of mucking with `data` explicitly. I found

```
def sp_min_nz_positive(asp,bsp):  # a and b scipy sparse
    amax = asp.max()
    bmax = bsp.max()
    abmaxplus = max(amax, bmax) # + 1.0 : surprise! not needed.
    # invert the direction, while remaining positive
    arev = asp.copy()
    arev.data[:] = abmaxplus - asp.data[:]
    brev = bsp.copy()
    brev.data[:] = abmaxplus - bsp.data[:]
    out = arev.maximum(brev)  # 
    # revert the direction of these positives
    out.data[:] = abmaxplus - out.data[:]
    return out
```

there may be inexactness due to roundoff

There was also a suggestion to use sparse internals.  A rather generic
function is `sp.find` which returns the nonzero elements of *anything*.

So you could also try out a `minimum` that **handles negative values too**, with something like:

```
import scipy.sparse as sp
def sp_min_union(a, b):
    assert a.shape == b.shape
    assert sp.issparse(a) and sp.issparse(b)
    (ra,ca,_) = sp.find(a)   # over nonzeros only
    (rb,cb,_) = sp.find(b)   # over nonzeros only
    setab = set(zip(ra,ca)).union(zip(rb,cb)) # row-column union-of-nonzero
    r=[]
    c=[]
    v=[]
    for (rr,cc) in setab:
        r.append(rr)
        c.append(cc)
        anz = a[rr,cc]
        bnz = b[rr,cc]
        assert anz!=0 or bnz!=0   # they came from *some* sp.find
        if anz==0: anz = bnz
        #else:
        #    #if bnz==0: anz = anz
        #    #else:      anz=min(anz,bnz)
        # equiv.
        elif bnz!=0: anz=min(anz,bnz)
        v.append(anz)
    # choose what sparse output format you want, many seem
    # constructible as:
    return sp.csr_matrix((v, (r,c)), shape=a.shape)
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, I can't check this out right away, but I'll try to have a look in the coming weeks to compare the different implementations :)